# C# Manipulate String List with List.ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a list as the following, and I would like to add a "!" at the end of each element of the string list.

I know that I can easily achieve this by using the traditional foreach. I'm wondering how do I do it with list.ForEach()?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hi");
list.Add("Hey");
list.Add("Cool");
list.Add("Nice Day");
```

I have tried this but it is not working for some reason.

```
list.ForEach(x => x += "!");
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using the foreach?

Comment: `List.ForEach` is not LINQ. It's a .NET 2 method.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the foreach, I'm just trying to learn the other way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, `ForEach` is a method of `List`, not a LINQ method.

Next, in your method there `x` is a *copy* of the item in the list, and you're mutating that copy to add a `!` to it, which is why the underlying list is unaffected.

LINQ is for *querying* data sources, so if you wanted to create an entirely new sequence/structure that has all of the strings that your list has, but with an exclamation at the end, you can use `Select` for that:

```
var IMPORTANT = list.Select(s => s + "!");
```

If you want to mutate the items, just use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    list[i] += "!";
```

Note that if you tried to use a `foreach` loop here, rather than a `for`, you'd run into the exact same problem that you have with your `ForEach` method.  Consider this case:

```
foreach(var s in list)
    s += "!";
```

Here `s` is a copy of the item in the list.  You're mutating the copy, leaving the item in the list unchanged.  If your list contained mutatable data, rather than immutable data, you could mutate the *item that the reference referred to*, rather than *mutating the reference itself* and a `foreach` or `ForEach` would work fine.

Comment: @gleng Sprelling is hurd.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = list.Select( x => x + "!" ).ToList()
```

Comment: While this works it is fundamentally different than `ForEach`. It has a void return type where `Select` does a projection and produces a new `IEnumberable<T>` (in this case T = string).

Comment: This reqires to create a new list via `ToList` which is less efficient than a simple `for`-loop.

Comment: And little bit about returning statements:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/02/01/demystifying-the-c-yield-return-mechanism.aspx